# npm install mongoose fails on windows8, as it tries to access Visual studio 2008 binaries which are not available

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Npm installations seem to fail on win8: 
npm install mongojs
npm install mongoose

Reason is that npm tries to access Visual Studio 2008 binaries, which are not available. If anybody knows how to fix this. I can't and nether want to install visual studio 2008.

I get this error:

Cannot open include file: 'winsock2.h': No such file or directory

Comment: Do you have some other version of Visual Studio installed?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. install Window SDK for window8
2. Open "**Window SDK Command Prompt**" from Window SDK program folder
3. try to npm install